# New relic infra agent on azure Virtual machine scale set

Tags: azure-aks, newrelic, azure-vm-scale-set, newrelic-platform

I would like to install and configure newrelic infra agent on VMSS. I have explored links but couldn't find any helpful. Could anyone help to start working on this?
I could see the following link but this is working for VM but not for VMSS.Though I installed extension in azure VMSS but its not even showing the name of VMSS in new relic.Also I am not looking for hem chart installation as helm chart installation of new relic is giving all the metics in newrelic which client doesn't require as we are monitoring other metrics from log analytics.
Appreciated quick help.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/install-infrastructure-agent/linux-installation/azure-extensions-infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you use the **ARM template** for installing the ***Relic*** agent in Linux based VMSS. For that purpose, please include the below ‘Relic’ **extension installation snippet** in your VMSS ARM deployment template and then try to check in new relic portal: -

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/extensions",
               
                        "name": "newrelic-infra",
                        "properties": {
               
                        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                        "publisher": "NewRelic.Infrastructure.Extensions",
                        "type": "newrelic-infra",
                        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
                        "settings": {
                            "NR_LICENSE_KEY": "PUT YOUR LICENSE HERE"
                            }

                        }

                    }
```

•   Also, you can try installing the **Azure Virtual machine scale sets** monitoring integration feature in your VMSS deployed. This can help you to report data from specific systems and supplement infrastructure's default, automatic monitoring. Microsoft Azure integrations **report data from various Azure platform services to your New Relic account**.

To activate Azure integration, please refer to the relic documentation below: -

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/microsoft-azure-integrations/get-started/activate-azure-integrations/

Once you have activated Azure integration, you can configure and poll the data using configuration options, then find and use the data retrieved from it to query and explore it and use them in forming compliance and other policy making decisions. For more details on knowing the integration features, please find the link below: -

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/microsoft-azure-integrations/azure-integrations-list/azure-virtual-machine-scale-sets-monitoring-integration/

Comment: Thanks for responding.My client wants to run the newrelic either through custom data via scripts or using terraform scripts.With terrafrom script I need to provision azure VMSS and install newrelic during VMSS provisioning. Could you please provide the necessary documents.We are not using ARM templates unfortunately.Client is very strict about it.So need to do this new relic installation via custom data through scripts during provisioning of VMSS in azure.

Comment: May I ask how you know that it takes `NR_LICENSE_KEY` how exactly did you find that?